# Check if an element exists with Selenium, JavaScript, and Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium

I'm trying to check if an element exists before I can execute this line:

`driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('test'));`

This throws an error "no such element" if the id `test` doesn't exist in the document, even in a `try`-block.
I've found answers for Java, where you can check if the size is 0, but in Node.js this throws an error before I can check the size:

`throw error; ^ NoSuchElementError: no such element`

Comment: Can't you just use this : if(webdriver.By.id('test')){ driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('test')); }.

Comment: findElements() and size()

Comment: @user2389688 webdriver.by.id("anything") seems to always result in true.

Comment: @epascarello `TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'size'`

Comment: ah, size() would be the Java version. Maybe swap size with .length and see if that works. I only played with the node version a little. Would something like this work

`driver.findElements(By.id('XXX')).then(function(elements) {
    var count = elements.length;
});`

Comment: Yes this works, submit it as an answer and I'll check it, thanks!

Comment: You should switch the accepted answer, so the right one is easier to find :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can leverage the optional error handler argument of `then()`.

```
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('test')).then(function(webElement) {
        console.log('Element exists');
    }, function(err) {
        if (err.state && err.state === 'no such element') {
            console.log('Element not found');
        } else {
            webdriver.promise.rejected(err);
        }
    });
```

I couldn't find it explicitly stated in the documentation, but determined this from the function definition in `webdriver/promise.js` in the `selenium-webdriver` module source:

```
  /**
   * Registers a callback on this Deferred.
   * @param {Function=} opt_callback The callback.
   * @param {Function=} opt_errback The errback.
   * @return {!webdriver.promise.Promise} A new promise representing the result
   *     of the callback.
   * @see webdriver.promise.Promise#then
   */
  function then(opt_callback, opt_errback) {
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it is the only that demonstrates how to determine is an element exists using the NodeJS Web Driver.

Comment: Unless the op is mistaken on using python not javascript, this should be the correct answer. Up voted!

Comment: in my case, the `err` object doesn't have a "state" prop. it returns this if i console log the error `{ NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"img"}`. and the second condition returns `TypeError: Cannot read property 'promise' of undefined`

Comment: Hi @Zugwait , may I just ask if it is possible to use `then` after a `driver.findElement(By.xpath('test')).click()` ? Thanks!

Comment: @Zugwalt Grateful for the answer, however how would you implement it in a scenario where you use `await`? I tried `await driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('test')).then(function(webElement) {
        console.log('Element exists');
    }, function(err) {...` but it throws an error

Comment: @JPaulPunzalan an Promise in that library should have the `then()` interface.
@Malky.Kid if using `await` I imagine you could just surround with a `try`/`catch` and not use `then()`.

Comment: The question is for JavaScript, but is there something similar for Python?

Answer (score 2):

Just use the isElementPresent(locatorOrElement) method. Here's a link to the code:

http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/source/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js.src.html#l777

Comment: link is broken, I don't think that function exists anymore

Comment: *"404. That’s an error."*

Comment: Though the OP has left the building: *"Last seen more than 5 years ago"*

Comment: From [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148857/check-if-element-exists-selenium-javascript-node-js/62069633#62069633): *"WebDriver#isElementPresent() and WebElement#isElementPresent() have been deprecated. These methods were removed in v3.0."*

Answer (score 2):

[Aaron Silverman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148857/check-if-an-element-exists-with-selenium-javascript-and-node-js/20977989#20977989) did not work as expected (`err.state` was `undefined` and a `NoSuchElementError` was always thrown)—though the concept of using the optional callbacks still works.

Since I was getting the same error as the OP is referencing, I believe [`NoSuchElementError`](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/error_exports_NoSuchElementError.html) should be referenced when determining if the targeted element exists or not. As its name implies, it is the error that is thrown when an element does not exist. So the condition in the errorCallback should be:

`err instanceof webdriver.error.NoSuchElementError`

So the complete code block would be as follows (I also am using `async`/`await` for those taking advantage of that syntax):

```
var existed = await driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('test')).then(function() {
    return true; // It existed
}, function(err) {
    if (err instanceof webdriver.error.NoSuchElementError) {
        return false; // It was not found
    } else {
        webdriver.promise.rejected(err);
    }
});
// Handle value of existed appropriately here
```

Comment: Tried this example, but now it says that 'webdriver' is undefined. tried getting it with "var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver')" in the beginning of the file, but now it says that there's no property 'promise' in that variable. How could I implement that condition in that case?

Comment: @LeonardoMontenegro I'm presuming the current version of the nodejs `selenium-webdriver` has updated and the properties of the webdriver have changed. 

I'd advise to go checkout the spec for the webdriver, it's possible they made the framework more stable and the  hacky solutions in the post are no longer needed :fingers-crossed: If I get some free time I'll check it out as I probably have code I'll need to update somewhere as a result >_< Let me know if you find anything?

Comment: @drasko kokic's answer below actually might be the solution (because of version updates and method/rpoperty deprecation):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62069633/1992129

Answer (score 1):

[Aaron Silverman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148857/check-if-an-element-exists-with-selenium-javascript-and-node-js/20977989#20977989) did not work for me fully, though some parts of it were helpful. [Arthur Weborg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148857/check-if-an-element-exists-with-selenium-javascript-and-node-js/45273140#45273140) worked for me, though some parts caused issues.

My typical use case for "checking if element exists" is when I want to click the element, only if it exists, since if it doesn't exist, it crashes the program due to the error.  All I want is for the application to note that it doesn't exist, and move on.  So what I do is:

```
await driver.findElement(By.id("test")).then(found => {
  driver.findElement(By.id("test")).click()
}, error => {
  if (error instanceof webdriver.error.NoSuchElementError) {
    console.log('Element not found.');
  }
});
```

Just a simple console log, and it moves on with the rest of the program like I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You want to check whether an element exists before you want to find an element in the UI. You can wait until the element gets located in the UI, and then you can perform the find element operation.

Example: Below code waits until the element located, and then it will perform the find element.

```
driver.wait(webdriver.until.elementLocated(webdriver.By.id(LocatorValue)), 20000)
.then(() => {
    return driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('test'));
}).then((element) => {
    // Perform any operation what you to do.
    return element.click();
}).catch(() => {
    console.log('Element not found');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that worked for me.

```
var assert = require('assert');
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var should = require('chai').should();
var chai = require('chai');
var chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');

chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
chai.should();

var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
By = webdriver.By;
until = webdriver.until;

describe('checking if an element id exists', function() {

  it.only('element id exists', function () {
    var driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
    driver.get('http://localhost:3000');
    this.timeout(6000);

    return driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id('idWeWantToTest')), 5 * 1000).then((e) => {
    }, function(err) {
      throw {
        msg: "element not found"
      }
    }).then(() => {
      driver.quit();
    });
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the summary for newbies like me ;-)

As described [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/3dfc66be727369f2d9083a7e69bb2f2b12d1c440):

For consistency with the other Selenium language bindings, `WebDriver#isElementPresent()` and `WebElement#isElementPresent()` have been deprecated. These methods will be removed in v3.0. Use the `findElements` command to test for the presence of an element:

```
  driver.findElements(By.css('.foo')).then(found => !!found.length);
```

Comment: This looks promising and cleaner than my solution from a couple years ago. I'll check this out and if it works, will upvote (TBD on when I have the time to test it out)

Comment: `findElements` seems to  have been deprecated as well. From [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30002313/selenium-finding-elements-by-class-name-in-python#comment128785684_30025430): *"`find_element_by_*` and `find_elements_by_*` are removed in Selenium 4.3.0. Use `find_element` instead."*. Though it doesn't really answer the question what can be done if the number of elements is different from exactly one.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible cases for this answer:

1. Case 1: Using promises
2. Case 2: Using `async` / `await`

Case 1 using promises, `then()` and the error callback is already well explained in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20977989/1852005).

In Case 2, if you're in an `async` function (and therefore likely to be using `await` statements), then you have the pleasure of avoiding all the nasty chaining of `then()`'s and callbacks.

In this scenario, you can simply check if an element exists with code like this:

```js
const check = async (webdriver) => {
  let elementExists;

  // Solution HERE:
  try {
    await webdriver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('test'));
    elementExists = true;
  } catch (error) { // error thrown is: "NoSuchElementError: no such element"
    elementExists = false;
  }

  if (elementExists) {
    // Element exists behaviour...
  } else {
    // Element doesn't exist behaviour...
  }
};
```