# TypeError: driver.isElementPresent is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium

I am attempting to write a node function that logs into a website and  am having trouble getting it to work.  I am trying to wait for the page to load using the `isElementPresent` function, referenced in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753014/selenium-webdriver-wait-till-element-is-displayed) but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here's what I have so far:

```
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver')
const By = webdriver.By

var username = ''
var password = ''
var timeout = 5000

function FacebookLogin(username, password) {

    var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
        .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome())
        .build()

    driver.get('http://www.facebook.com')

    driver.wait(function() {
        return driver.isElementPresent(By.id('email'))
    }, timeout)

    var user = driver.findElement(By.id('email'))
    user.sendKeys(username)

    var pass = driver.findElement(By.id('pass'))
    pass.sendKeys(password)

    pass.submit()
    driver.sleep(5000)
    driver.quit()
}

FacebookLogin(username, password)
```

When I run the function though I receive the error `TypeError: driver.isElementPresent is not a function`.  What is going on here and what am I missing?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[For consistency with the other Selenium language bindings,  `WebDriver#isElementPresent()` and `WebElement#isElementPresent()` have been deprecated.](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/3dfc66be727369f2d9083a7e69bb2f2b12d1c440)

If you're using `Selenium 3`, you should try using `findElements` instead to determine element present or not as below :-

```
driver.findElements(By.id('email')).then(found => !!found.length);
```

Or if you want to wait until desire element present, you should try using [`webdriver.until`](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/until.html) as below :-

```
const until = webdriver.until;

var user = driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id('email')), timeout);
user.sendKeys(username);
```

Comment: but how can I replace this my code for selenium 3?

`driver.wait(function () {

        return driver.isElementPresent(By.css(".form-control")); 

    }, 10000);`

Comment: @Saurabh Gaur driver.findElements(By.id('email')).then(found => !!found.length); fails with an error if email is not present in DOM. How can I avoid it?

Comment: @SaurabhGaur https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50806848/check-if-element-is-present-in-protractor

Comment: @user911 actually you are trying with `findElement` while I'm suggesting it using `findElements`...us it instead.. it would return either list of element or empty list..thanks..:)

Comment: 'if(driver.findElements(By.id('email')).size()>0){ //do something}'  - can be used as well.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that all of the dependencies like Selenium and the browser driver are installed and working using a very minimal example.

Then you can check what functions are on the driver object with console.log(util.inspect(driver));

If your dependencies are set up, it may be that the API changed slightly.  The current example here https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver uses `until`.  You may want to try something closer to that example first.

Comment: I have verified dependencies have been installed.  Probably the API changed?  I can't seem to find any reference in the docs, http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/index.html.  Safe to say this function is no longer used?

Comment: Yes I guess it is no longer used.  Maybe elementLocated from 'until' https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/lib/until.js

Comment: until works, sort of.  It seems to fail intermittently but I think that issue is outside of this question.