# isElementPresent is not a function

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i wanted the driver to wait until a element is visible or present, but it is simply not working!
the following code

```
it('shows events in "Event overview"', function(){
        driver.findElement(By.css('#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1 > ul > li:nth-child(2) > a')).click();
        driver.wait(function () {
            return driver.isElementPresent(By.css('body > div.container > div > div.events-container.ng-scope > div:nth-child(1) > div.row.row-event.detailed-view > div.col-xs-9.col-sm-9.col-md-10'));
        }, 3000);
});
```

gives me the following error

```
driver.isElementPresent is not a function
```

why? i copied the answer from here: [Selenium WebDriver wait till element is displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753014/selenium-webdriver-wait-till-element-is-displayed). other answers dont work either. should i show more of my code? im working on a client project and i dont want to publish the name of the client.

Comment: `isElementPresent` is a Java method, not JavaScript ?

Comment: Wrongly tagged here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[I have already answered here for this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39736692/typeerror-driver-iselementpresent-is-not-a-function/39737701#39737701)

[For consistency with the other Selenium language bindings,  `WebDriver#isElementPresent()` and `WebElement#isElementPresent()` have been deprecated. It has been completely removed from Selenium v3](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/3dfc66be727369f2d9083a7e69bb2f2b12d1c440)

So if you're using `Selenium3` and want to wait until desire element present, you should try using [`webdriver.until`](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/until.html) as below :-

```
const until = webdriver.until;

var el = driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css('body > div.container > div > div.events-container.ng-scope > div:nth-child(1) > div.row.row-event.detailed-view > div.col-xs-9.col-sm-9.col-md-10')), 3000);
```

Comment: And what if I would like to wait until element is not present?

Answer (score -1):

try the following:

```
        return driver.findElements(By.css('body > div.container > div > div.events-container.ng-scope > div:nth-child(1) > div.row.row-event.detailed-view > div.col-xs-9.col-sm-9.col-md-10')).size() != 0;
```