# check if element is present in protractor

Tags: angular, protractor

I have an angular application where user can get a different login screen(non-angular) based on her/his browser cache. I am writing end to end test cases using protractor and I want to put a condition something like this

```
if(this element is present)
{
click it
}
else check if this element is pressent
{
click it
}
```

This is what I have tried.

```
  browser.driver.findElements(by.id('element1')).then(function(result) {
      if (result) {
        browser.driver.findElement(by.id('element1')).click();
      }
      else {
        browser.driver.findElement(by.id('element2')).sendKeys("username");
      }
    }
  );
```

My issue is that if the element in the 'if condition' is not present then I am getting an error ' `Failed: no such element: Unable to locate element:`'. I don't want my test cases to fail because it's possible that the element is not present and then it should go to else block.
I have seen so many questions on stackoverflow but nothing helped me. I would really appreciate any help here.

Update: please note that this is a non-angular screen and I can only use browser.driver.______ apis.

Comment: Does it help to replace if (result) with if (result.length>0)?

Comment: @Jeremy Kahan Guess what!! It worked!! Thank you so much! If you can write it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very much on the right track. Because findElements returns an array, you just needed to change what you had  `if (result)` to `if (result.length>0)`. With FindElements, finding nothing is not an error.