# Why using inbuilt webdriver wait yields an error "ReferenceError: until is not defined"?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Webdriverjs apparently has an inbuilt method which allows you to wait for an element.

```
var saveButton = driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath("//div[text() = 'Save']")), 5000);
driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(saveButton), 5000).click();
```

Using this method results in an error "ReferenceError: until is not defined".
Why is this method not working?

Comment: try this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753014/selenium-webdriver-wait-till-element-is-displayed

Answer (score 9):

I read the webdriverjs docs and the example given there is missing 'webdriver' keyword.

```
var saveButton = driver.wait(webdriver.until.elementLocated(webdriver.By.xpath("//div[text() = 'Save']")), 5000);
driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(saveButton), 5000).click();
```

Adding 'webdriver' keyword before 'until' and 'By' solves the issue.

Answer (score 9):

The most common best practice is to require `webdriver.By` and `webdriver.until` at the top of your file right after you require webdriver.

then you don't have to do `webdriver.By` inside your tests, you can do `driver(By.css())`

Comment: could you provide an example as to how this is written?

Comment: var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    By = webdriver.By,
    until = webdriver.until;

Comment: You can also solve this problem by adding By and until to the require section:
const { Builder, By, until } = require("selenium-webdriver");

Comment: Yes, this is the recommended way since the new async/await syntax

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure the language binding you are using. Using Java bindings, in Selenium 3.x releases `until` must be accompanied by `ExpectedConditions`

So, to apply ExplicitWait on an element & click it, your code must look like:

```
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
    WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[text() = 'Save']"))); 
    element.click();
```

Let me know if this solves your Question.

Comment: asked question is not in java.