# NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to locate element through WebdriverJS

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

I was using css to locate element, i was trying to avoid xpath just in case, but im having trouble with the element. Im still getting error:

```
(node:7516) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name-firstName]"}
```

It only works on xpath, but i want to use css locator. Is it a good practice to avoid xpath when locating element? thank you guys!

Here is the whole element:

```
<input type="text" class="f w-input ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" name="firstName" required="" ng-readonly="vm.showLoading" ng-model="vm.formData.firstName" placeholder="Your First Name">
```

Here is the code trial :

```
driver.get("www.examplewebsiteonly.com")
    .then(function() {
        return driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css('[name=firstName]')), 20000)
        .then(function(){
            driver.sleep(20000)
            .then(function(){
                        return driver.findElement(By.css('[name-firstName]')).sendKeys("FirstName");
                    })
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't using the same CSS selector in both instances. Change

```
[name-firstName]
```

to

```
[name='firstName']
```

in the second instance.

Also, your code looks overly complicated. Have you tried something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29156163/2386774)?

Comment: When you say `not working` - does it throw any error or does it not do anything? Please clarify.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19717997)

Comment: @AtulSharma Sure it does. The question title is referring to a `NoSuchElementError`. The error text provided shows that the CSS selector, `[name-firstName]`, was used which is incorrect given the provided HTML. The OP requested a CSS selector so I corrected it. What do you think the OP's question is that I didn't answer?

Comment: Is this element in an `IFRAME`?

Answer (score 0):

When you've a `name` attribute, you can use

```
driver.get("www.examplewebsiteonly.com")
    .then(function() {
        return driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.name("firstName")), 20000)
        .then(function(){
            driver.sleep(20000)
            .then(function(){
                        return driver.findElement(By.name("firstName")).sendKeys("FirstName");
                    })
        })
    })
```

I replaced the `css` selector with the `name` selector that Selenium provides. Also single quotes removed to add double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML you have shared to identify the desired element you can use either of the following *Locator Strategies* :

- `css` :

  ```
  return driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css("input.f.w-input.ng-pristine.ng-invalid.ng-invalid-required.ng-touched[name='firstName'][placeholder='Your First Name']")), 20000)
  ```
- `xpath` :

  ```
  return driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@class='f w-input ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched' and @name='firstName'][@ng-model=\"vm.formData.firstName\"]")), 20000)
  ```