# Can not find element in XPath with Selenium driver

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver, element

Every time I load up python script the Xpath for the Facebook login button and popup button has to changed manually every time before I login. How do I change this so that I dont have to enter the XPath manually?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

class TinderBot():
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    def login(self):
        self.driver.get('https://tinder.com')

        sleep(3)

        #fbxpath = //button[@type = 'button' and @aria-label = 'Log in with Facebook']

        fb_btn = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/div[1]/div/div/main/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/span/div[2]/button')
        fb_btn.click()

        base_window = self.driver.window_handles[0]
        self.driver.switch_to_window(self.driver.window_handles[1])
        fbemail = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="email"]')
        fbemail.send_keys('ara_98425@yahoo.com')

        fbpass = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pass"]')
        fbpass.send_keys('BlackToast5')

        login_btn = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="u_0_0"]')
        login_btn.click()

        self.driver.switch_to_window(base_window)

        popup1 = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="modal-manager"]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/button[1]')
        popup1.click()

        popup2 = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="modal-manager"]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/button[1]')
        popup2.click()

bot = TinderBot()
bot.login()
```

This is the error I get:

```
File "tind_bt.py", line 16, in login
    fb_btn = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/div[1]/div/div/main/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/span/div[2]/button')
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="content"]/div/div[1]/div/div/main/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/span/div[2]/button"}
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.106)
```

Comment: Try to use class, id etc. Avoid to use absolute xpaths

Comment: <button type="button" class="button Lts($ls-s) Z(0) CenterAlign Mx(a) Cur(p) Tt(u) Bdrs(100px) Px(24px) Px(20px)--s Py(0) Mih(54px) Pos(r) Ov(h) C(#fff) Bg($c-pink):h::b Bg($c-pink):f::b Bg($c-pink):a::b Trsdu($fast) Trsp($background) Bg($primary-gradient) button--primary-shadow StyledButton Fw($semibold) focus-button-style Mb(20px) W(100%) P(0)" draggable="false" aria-label="Log in with Facebook"><span class="Pos(r) Z(1) D(ib)">Log in with Facebook</span></button>

Comment: thats the element.. how would I write an XPath for it?

Comment: //button[@aria-label='Log in with Facebook']

Answer (score 1):

You were close. To invoke `click()` on the element with text as **Log in with Facebook** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` reaching till the child `<span>` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[type = 'button'][aria-label = 'Log in with Facebook'] span"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@type = 'button' and @aria-label = 'Log in with Facebook']//span"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: tinder_facebook_login]

---

### Reference

You can find a detailed relevant discussion in:

- [Selenium “selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException” when using Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294)

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you can implement the WebDriverWait and see if that takes care of the problem.

This might get you started - [Selenium WebDriver wait till element is displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753014/selenium-webdriver-wait-till-element-is-displayed)

Here's the Python documentation for explicit waits - https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: how would I do it with python?

Comment: You can try to follow this link and see if it works for you - <https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html>

Comment: <button type="button" class="button Lts($ls-s) Z(0) CenterAlign Mx(a) Cur(p) Tt(u) Bdrs(100px) Px(24px) Px(20px)--s Py(0) Mih(54px) Pos(r) Ov(h) C(#fff) Bg($c-pink):h::b Bg($c-pink):f::b Bg($c-pink):a::b Trsdu($fast) Trsp($background) Bg($primary-gradient) button--primary-shadow StyledButton Fw($semibold) focus-button-style Mb(20px) W(100%) P(0)" draggable="false" aria-label="Log in with Facebook"><span class="Pos(r) Z(1) D(ib)">Log in with Facebook</span></button>

Comment: how would u write an xpath for that or which attribute should i use for the xpath?

Comment: I guess you would write something similar to this after importing the following - from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

Then on your fbemail = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="email"]') you would switch that to - fbemail = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.xpath, "myDynamicXpath")))

Comment: @ArvindDexterThillainathan I use Chropath to find the xpath. I find it easier to use that instead of manually trying to come up with one on my own. You can learn more about it here - <https://autonomiq.io/chropath/>