# Finding elements by class name with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, classname

How can I filter elements that have the same class?

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <p class="content">Link1.</p>
  </body>
</html>
<html>
  <body>
    <p class="content">Link2.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 91):

You can try to get the list of all elements with `class = "content"` by using [**find_elements_by_class_name**](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html):

```
a = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("content")
```

Then you can click on the link that you are looking for.

Comment: Does it return all elements of the class or the first found?

Comment: Why are you even initializing `a` as an empty list if you immediately reassign it?

Comment: @keerthankumar this return list of all the elements. To get the 1st one use `find_element_by_class_name`

Comment: You don't need the semicolon at the end of python line of code.

Comment: Now how to click on the class name after selecting it? `.click()` attribute doesn't work!

Comment: `find_element_by_*` and `find_elements_by_*` are removed in Selenium 4.3.0. Use `find_element` instead. Look at all change logs [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/a4995e2c096239b42c373f26498a6c9bb4f2b3e7/py/CHANGES).

Comment: @Parampreet Rai: Though `find_element()` [throws an exception if the element doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9567069/checking-if-an-element-exists-with-python-selenium#comment117614846_36166132).

Comment: @PeterMortensen you can still use `find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'foo')` to get a list of elements

Answer (score 54):

**By.CLASS_NAME** was not yet mentioned:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "content")
```

---

[This is the list of attributes](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=#module-selenium.webdriver.common.by) which can be used as locators in By:

> `CLASS_NAME`
>   `CSS_SELECTOR`
>   `ID`
>   `LINK_TEXT`
>   `NAME`
>   `PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT`
>   `TAG_NAME`
>   `XPATH`

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. The alternative of using find_element_by_class_name wouldn't work at all for me, even if I used a wait.

Comment: But it throws an exception if it doesn't exist(?). Thus disrupting the test run.

Comment: Actually the question is for "elements" plural so driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "content") wouldn't get all right?

Answer (score 32):

As per the HTML:

```html
<html>
    <body>
    <p class="content">Link1.</p>
    </body>
<html>
<html>
    <body>
    <p class="content">Link2.</p>
    </body>
<html>
```

Two(2) `<p>` elements are having the same class `content`.

So to filter the elements having the same class i.e. `content` and create a *list* you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `class_name`:

  ```
  elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("content")
  ```
- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
   elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".content")
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='content']")
  ```

---

Ideally, to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following *Locator Strategies*:

- Using `CLASS_NAME`:

  ```
  elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "content")))
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".content")))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@class='content']")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to identify an element through classname even though there are multiple elements with the same classnames using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62151967/how-to-identify-an-element-through-classname-even-though-there-are-multiple-elem/62152196#62152196)
- [Unable to locate element using className in Selenium and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62948150/unable-to-locate-element-using-classname-in-selenium-and-java/62949723#62949723)
- [What are properties of find_element_by_class_name in selenium python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62716634/what-are-properties-of-find-element-by-class-name-in-selenium-python/62716829#62716829)
- [How to locate the last web element using classname attribute through Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62957266/how-to-locate-the-last-web-element-using-classname-attribute-through-selenium-an/62959237#62959237)

Comment: Neither class name nor css selector worked, no idea why, but xpath did, thanks a lot for that

Comment: From [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30002313/selenium-finding-elements-by-class-name-in-python#comment128785684_30025430): *"`find_element_by_*` and `find_elements_by_*` are removed in Selenium 4.3.0. Use `find_element` instead."*

Answer (score 14):

Use nth-child, for example: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'p.content:nth-child(1)')
```

or http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'p.content:first-child')
```

Answer (score 12):

The most simple way is to use [`find_element_by_class_name('class_name')`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_class_name)

Answer (score 4):

The first answer has been deprecated, and the other answers only return one result. This is the correct answer:

```
driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "content")
```

Comment: Yes, they missed the plural, "elements". However, *find_elements* itself [is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30002313/selenium-finding-elements-by-class-name-in-python#comment128785684_30025430).

Comment: What do you mean by "the first answer"? Highest scored? Chronological first? References to relative positions of answers are not reliable as they depend on the view (votes/oldest/active) and changing of the accepted answer and change over time (for votes, active, and accepted state).

Comment: To be fair, it wasn't missed in [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30002313/finding-elements-by-class-name-with-selenium-in-python/63329510#63329510).

Answer (score 0):

The question was related to "elements" plural, most are for element.
To wait for the element and then iterate over each:

```
selectableEls = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "content")))
for el in selectableEls:
    print(el)
```

Answer (score -1):

In Python, Selenium provides a method called find_elements_by_class_name to find elements with the same class name. This method returns a list of all elements that match the provided class name.

Let's say you're trying to find all paragraphs (

) with the class "content". Here's how you can do it:

from selenium import webdriver

## initialize the driver

driver = webdriver.Firefox() # replace with the browser driver of your choice

## navigate to your webpage

driver.get('https://www.softwaretestingsapiens.com/finding-elements-by-class-name-with-selenium-in-python/')

## find elements by class name

elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('content')

for el in elements:
print(el.text)

This script will print the text inside each

tag with the class "content". In your case, it should print "Link1." and "Link2.".

Remember, [Selenium](https://www.softwaretestingsapiens.com/finding-elements-by-class-name-with-selenium-in-python/) requires a specific driver to interface with the chosen browser. Firefox requires geckodriver, which needs to be installed before the above script can be run.

Also, keep in mind that find_elements_by_class_name returns a list, even if there's only one match. If you're certain there's only one element of interest, use find_element_by_class_name (note the lack of 's' in 'element') to get the WebElement directly.

Lastly, it's recommended to add some error handling to your script to manage situations where the elements are not found. This will make your code more robust and easier to debug.

Happy coding!

Comment: Are you aware of our [policy forbidding AI-generated answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/354577)?