# Selecting an element by tag name with specific text in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, automated-tests

I have this HTML

```html
<div class="callout callout-accordion" style="background-image: url(&quot;/images/expand.png&quot;);">
    <span class="edit" data-pk="bandwidth_bar">Bandwidth Settings</span>
    <span class="telnet-arrow"></span>
</div>
```

I'm trying to select **span** with text = `Bandwidth Settings`, and click on the **div** with class name = `callout`.

```python
if driver.find_element_by_tag_name("span") == ("Bandwidth Settings"):
    print "Found"
    time.sleep(100)
    driver.find_element_by_tag_name("div").find_element_by_class_name("callout").click()

print "Not found"
time.sleep(100)
```

I kept getting

```
Testing started at 1:59 PM ...
Not found

Process finished with exit code 0
```

---

What did I miss?

---

#### Select the parent *div*

```python
    if driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Bandwidth Settings']") is None:
        print "Not Found"
    else:
        print "Found"
        span = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Bandwidth Settings']")
        div = span.find_element_by_xpath('..')
        div.click()
```

I got

> WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element

Comment: driver.find_element_by_tag_name("span")  will find more than one element

Comment: Ohh. I see. How can I select a span with a `text == 'string'` ?

Comment: Please try use class instead of span 

    driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("Edit")).Text

Comment: I got this `AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'FindElement'` - what do I need to import to use that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use `find_element_by_xpath(xpath)` like this:

```
if driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(.,'Bandwidth Settings')]") is None:
   print "Not found"
else:
   print "Found"
   ...
```

For an exact match (as you asked for in your comment), use `"//span[text()='Bandwidth Settings']"`

On your *edited* question, try one of these:

Locate directly (if there is no other matching element):

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[style*='/images/telenet/expand.png']")
```

Locate via *span* (provided there isn't any other *div* on that level):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(.,'Bandwidth Settings')]/../div")
```

Comment: How do select the parent div of that ??

Comment: I've tried `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.callout").click()` , it click on the first one it found :(

Comment: All `find_element`methods are designed to return the _first_ element that matches. So you should use them, if you have a _unique_ locator (or you do not care for the rest of the mathcing elements on page). Alternatively, you can use the `find_elements` methods (notice the plural) which return a list of all matching `WebElement` objects. You can then iterate that list. But I am not so much into python to give you a syntactically correct example right away.

Comment: I've tried `if driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Bandwidth Settings']") is None:
            print "Not Found"
        else :
            print "Found"
            span = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Bandwidth Settings']")
            div = span.find_element_by_xpath('..')
            div.click()`

Comment: @Würgspaß, wrong! `span=driver.find_element_...(...)` `span.find_element_...(...)` is correct syntax

Comment: From [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30002313/selenium-finding-elements-by-class-name-in-python#comment128785684_30025430): *"`find_element_by_*` and `find_elements_by_*` are removed in Selenium 4.3.0. Use `find_element` instead."*.

Answer (score 0):

The code that you need to use:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

try:
    span = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[text()="Bandwidth Settings"]')
    print "Found"
except NoSuchElementException:
    print "Not found"
```

If you need to select the parent `div` element:

```
div = span.find_element_by_xpath('./parent::div')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have sizzle on the page ([jQuery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery)) you can select spans by their text like so:

```javascript
$("span:contains('Bandwidth Settings')")
```

Which would be selected like so using the [C#](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29) bindings:

```csharp
By.CssSelector("span:contains('Bandwidth Settings')")
```

Comment: What is "sizzle"?