# Selenium: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<CustomListeners> to Class<? extends ITestNGListener>[]

Tags: selenium, testng, listeners

I am using TestNG framework. I have a `Test1` class which extends `BaseTestSuite`. Also I have a `CustomListeners` class which implements `WebDriverEventListener`. When I use `@Listeners(CustomListeners.class)` annotation in the Test class, getting following error. Please help to resolve.

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<CustomListeners> to Class<? extends ITestNGListener>[]
```

**Test Class**

```
@Listeners(CustomListeners.class) //Error line
public class Test1 extends BaseTestSuite {

    LoginPage lp;
    TabMenu tm;

    @Test(priority = 0, testName = "Verify Login")
    public void login() throws Exception {
        lp = new LoginPage(driver, test);
        tm = new TabMenu(driver, test);
        driver.get(Constants.url);
        lp.verifyLoginPageLogo();
        lp.setUserName("dmin");
        lp.setPassword("admin");
        lp.clickLoginBtn();
        tm.verifyTabMenu();
        tm.isCurrentTab("Dashboard");
    }
}
```

**Listeners Class**

```
public class CustomListeners implements WebDriverEventListener {
/*
         * 
         * All Implemented methods
         * 
         * 
         */
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium is not part of TestNG. The WebDriverEventListener interface doesn't extend ITestNGListener. The two classes have nothing in common.
 TestNG requires a class that extends or implements one of the listeners for this to work.
To combine this two classes to work make your class CustomListeners extend the org.testng.TestListenerAdapter class, because it's the only listener class, and not an interface so you would not need to implement TestNG methods.

This should be your class declaration:

```
 public class CustomListeners extends TestListenerAdapter implements WebDriverEventListener
```

Try this workaround.

Comment: The IDE is not smart enough to check if you are sending the correct class to @Listeners annotation, it can check only that you are actually sending class.

Answer (score 1):

Like Kristijan Rusu wrote in his answer, the `WebDriverEventListener` interface and [ITestNGListener](http://static.javadoc.io/org.testng/testng/6.11/org/testng/ITestNGListener.html) Interface are meant for two separate purposes.

If you have written a class that implements `WebDriverEventListener` all you need to add this listener class to your driver object is create a new [EventFiringWebDriver](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/EventFiringWebDriver.html) object and pass your driver object to its constructor

`EventFiringWebDriver eventDriver = new EventFiringWebDriver(driver);`

after this it business as usual, eventDriver supports all the methods that your driver object supported.

Where as,

`ITestNGListener` has multiple [sub interfaces](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/testng-listeners/) such as `IAnnotationTransformer`, `IAnnotationTransformer2`, `IConfigurable`, `IConfigurationListener`, `IConfigurationListener2`, `IExecutionListener`, `IHookable`, `IInvokedMethodListener`, `IInvokedMethodListener2`, `IMethodInterceptor`, `IReporter`, `ISuiteListener`, `ITestListener`. These lets you write hooks for TestNG related events such as `onTestFailure`, `onStart` etc.

Comment: I tried the workaround `public class CustomListeners extends TestListenerAdapter implements WebDriverEventListener`, error disappears but none of my listeners work. Eg. `beforeFindBy`. A simple print statement is written inside the `beforeFindBy` method.

Comment: http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/event-listener/ follow this tutorial

Comment: Thanks. I just found that I missed to create an object of `CustomListerners` class and `register` in the driver. Now it works.