# Failed to execute 'elementsFromPoint' on 'Document': The provided double value is non-finite

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

So I am having issues with selenium clicking hidden nav bar in HTML...I need to click on the action button and then click on Export(Excel).

Currently, I have it set to aria-labeledby=share and this assumes I want to click Export(CSV) and performs the task (when the script wants to work...if not then I get the error below). When I try to set the `find_elements_by_css_selector()` or `find_elements_by_xpath()` and point it to Export(Excel) it doesn't work. So I currently have it set to aria-labeledby=Share and this works but randomly it will stop working and I will get the below error. I have never heard of WAI-Aria embedded into HTML until inspected the webpage element.

```
action = ActionChains(driver)

aria_lablededBy = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("[aria-labeledby=Actions]")[0]

action.move_to_element(aria_lablededBy).click(aria_lablededBy).perform()

share = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('[aria-labeledby=Share]')[0]

action.move_to_element(share).click(share).perform()
```

the above code works and then stops randomly and i get this error message

```
ERROR:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/Python/import/export.py", line 53, in <module>
        action.move_to_element(share).click(share).perform()
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\action_chains.py", line 80, in perform
        self.w3c_actions.perform()
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\actions\action_builder.py", line 76, in perform
        self.driver.execute(Command.W3C_ACTIONS, enc)
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
        self.error_handler.check_response(response)
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
        raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Failed to execute 'elementsFromPoint' on 'Document': The provided double value is non-finite.
      (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.88)
```

the HTML site that I am connecting to has Aria-HTML code and I am not familiar with that. I removed the shared variable and the following action on the shared variable and the script will open up the actions nav...once enable the shared variable and the action then it gives me the error

I am way out of my league on this problem so if anyone in the community knows how to solve this problem I am very interested.

HTML CODE - Action Menu Hidden

```
<lp-mega-menu _ngcontent-iyn-c45="" _nghost-iyn-c31="">
  <nav _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" class="dropdown" lpmegamenu="" role="menu" triggers="manual" id="KJ0X5NWLXZGZ8" aria-labeledby="Actions">
    <button _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="0" type="button" class="lp-themed-button lp-themed-primary-button" aria-controls="dropdown-menu-KJ0X5NWLXZGZ8" aria-expanded="false">
      <!----><!----><!----><span _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">Actions</span><i _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" class="fas fa-caret-down mr-0 ml-default-half"></i>
    </button>
    <div _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right mega-menu-panel my-2" id="dropdown-menu-KJ0X5NWLXZGZ8" aria-hidden="true" style="max-height: 600px;">
      <!---->
      <div _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" class="mega-menu-panel-wrapper label-reset ul-reset">
        <!----><!----><!---->
        <div _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" class="mega-menu-grid">
          <!----><!----><!---->
          <div _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" class="mega-menu-col">
            <div _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" class="mega-menu-body">
              <label _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">Authoring</label>
              <div _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" class="mega-menu-content">
                <ul _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" aria-labeledby="Authoring">
                  <!---->
                  <li _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">
                    <!----><a _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" class="lp-theme-link-focus lp-theme-link-hover lp-theme-link-active" tabindex="0" title="Add Record"><span _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">Add</span></a><!---->
                  </li>
                  <li _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">
                    <!----><a _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" class="lp-theme-link-focus lp-theme-link-hover lp-theme-link-active" tabindex="0" title="Filter Report"><span _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">Filters (0)</span></a><!---->
                  </li>
                  <li _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">
                    <!----><a _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" class="lp-theme-link-focus lp-theme-link-hover lp-theme-link-active" tabindex="0" title="Edit Report"><span _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">Edit</span></a><!---->
                  </li>
                  <li _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">
                    <!----><a _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" class="lp-theme-link-focus lp-theme-link-hover lp-theme-link-active" tabindex="0" title="Copy Report"><span _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">Copy</span></a><!---->
                  </li>
                  <li _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">
                    <!----><a _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" class="lp-theme-link-focus lp-theme-link-hover lp-theme-link-active" tabindex="0" title="Delete Report"><span _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">Delete</span></a><!---->
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!---->
          <div _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" class="mega-menu-col">
            <div _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" class="mega-menu-body">
              <label _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">Bulk Ops</label>
              <div _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" class="mega-menu-content">
                <ul _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" aria-labeledby="Bulk Ops">
                  <!---->
                  <li _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">
                    <!----><a _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" class="lp-theme-link-focus lp-theme-link-hover lp-theme-link-active" tabindex="0" title="Bulk Edit Records"><span _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">Edit</span></a><!---->
                  </li>
                  <li _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">
                    <!----><a _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" class="lp-theme-link-focus lp-theme-link-hover lp-theme-link-active" tabindex="0" title="Bulk Move Records"><span _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">Move</span></a><!---->
                  </li>
                  <li _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">
                    <!----><a _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" class="lp-theme-link-focus lp-theme-link-hover lp-theme-link-active" tabindex="0" title="Bulk Edit/Move Records"><span _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">Edit/Move</span></a><!---->
                  </li>
                  <li _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">
                    <!----><a _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" class="lp-theme-link-focus lp-theme-link-hover lp-theme-link-active" tabindex="0" title="Bulk Delete Records"><span _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">Delete</span></a><!---->
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!---->
          <div _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" class="mega-menu-col-md">
            <!----><!----><!---->
            <div _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" class="mega-menu-body">
              <label _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">Share</label>
              <div _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" class="mega-menu-content">
                <ul _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" aria-labeledby="Share">
                  <!---->
                  <li _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">
                    <!----><a _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" class="lp-theme-link-focus lp-theme-link-hover lp-theme-link-active" tabindex="0" title="Print a PDF"><span _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">Print (PDF)</span></a><!---->
                  </li>
                  <li _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">
                    <!----><a _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" class="lp-theme-link-focus lp-theme-link-hover lp-theme-link-active" tabindex="0" title="Export as Excel"><span _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">Export (Excel)</span></a><!---->
                  </li>
                  <li _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">
                    <!----><a _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" class="lp-theme-link-focus lp-theme-link-hover lp-theme-link-active" tabindex="0" title="Export as CSV"><span _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">Export (CSV)</span></a><!---->
                  </li>
                  <li _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">
                    <!----><a _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" class="lp-theme-link-focus lp-theme-link-hover lp-theme-link-active" tabindex="0" title="Copy Report Link"><span _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">Link</span></a><!---->
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!---->
    </div>
  </nav>
</lp-mega-menu>
```

HTML CODE - Action Menu Visible

```
<lp-mega-menu _ngcontent-iyn-c45="" _nghost-iyn-c31="">
  <nav _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" class="dropdown open" lpmegamenu="" role="menu" triggers="manual" id="KJ0X5NWLXZGZ8" aria-labeledby="Actions">
    <button _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="0" type="button" class="lp-themed-button lp-themed-primary-button" aria-controls="dropdown-menu-KJ0X5NWLXZGZ8" aria-expanded="true">
      <!----><!----><!----><span _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">Actions</span><i _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" class="fas fa-caret-down mr-0 ml-default-half"></i>
    </button>
  </nav>
</lp-mega-menu>
```

The below is part of the HTML - Action Menu Hidden code but once it the menu is visible the code is moved outside of this element:

```
<div _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right mega-menu-panel my-2" id="dropdown-menu-KJ0X5NWLXZGZ8" aria-hidden="false" style="max-height: 600px; display: block; height: 252px; right: 8px; top: 128px;">
<!---->
<div _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" class="mega-menu-panel-wrapper label-reset ul-reset">
  <!----><!----><!---->
  <div _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" class="mega-menu-grid">
    <!----><!----><!---->
    <div _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" class="mega-menu-col">
      <div _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" class="mega-menu-body">
        <label _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">Authoring</label>
        <div _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" class="mega-menu-content">
          <ul _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" aria-labeledby="Authoring">
            <!---->
            <li _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">
              <!----><a _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" class="lp-theme-link-focus lp-theme-link-hover lp-theme-link-active" tabindex="0" title="Add Record"><span _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">Add</span></a><!---->
            </li>
            <li _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">
              <!----><a _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" class="lp-theme-link-focus lp-theme-link-hover lp-theme-link-active" tabindex="0" title="Filter Report"><span _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">Filters (0)</span></a><!---->
            </li>
            <li _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">
              <!----><a _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" class="lp-theme-link-focus lp-theme-link-hover lp-theme-link-active" tabindex="0" title="Edit Report"><span _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">Edit</span></a><!---->
            </li>
            <li _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">
              <!----><a _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" class="lp-theme-link-focus lp-theme-link-hover lp-theme-link-active" tabindex="0" title="Copy Report"><span _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">Copy</span></a><!---->
            </li>
            <li _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">
              <!----><a _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" class="lp-theme-link-focus lp-theme-link-hover lp-theme-link-active" tabindex="0" title="Delete Report"><span _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">Delete</span></a><!---->
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!---->
    <div _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" class="mega-menu-col">
      <div _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" class="mega-menu-body">
        <label _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">Bulk Ops</label>
        <div _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" class="mega-menu-content">
          <ul _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" aria-labeledby="Bulk Ops">
            <!---->
            <li _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">
              <!----><a _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" class="lp-theme-link-focus lp-theme-link-hover lp-theme-link-active" tabindex="0" title="Bulk Edit Records"><span _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">Edit</span></a><!---->
            </li>
            <li _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">
              <!----><a _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" class="lp-theme-link-focus lp-theme-link-hover lp-theme-link-active" tabindex="0" title="Bulk Move Records"><span _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">Move</span></a><!---->
            </li>
            <li _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">
              <!----><a _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" class="lp-theme-link-focus lp-theme-link-hover lp-theme-link-active" tabindex="0" title="Bulk Edit/Move Records"><span _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">Edit/Move</span></a><!---->
            </li>
            <li _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">
              <!----><a _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" class="lp-theme-link-focus lp-theme-link-hover lp-theme-link-active" tabindex="0" title="Bulk Delete Records"><span _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">Delete</span></a><!---->
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!---->
    <div _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" class="mega-menu-col-md">
      <!----><!----><!---->
      <div _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" class="mega-menu-body">
        <label _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">Share</label>
        <div _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" class="mega-menu-content">
          <ul _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" aria-labeledby="Share">
            <!---->
            <li _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">
              <!----><a _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" class="lp-theme-link-focus lp-theme-link-hover lp-theme-link-active" tabindex="0" title="Print a PDF"><span _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">Print (PDF)</span></a><!---->
            </li>
            <li _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">
              <!----><a _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" class="lp-theme-link-focus lp-theme-link-hover lp-theme-link-active" tabindex="0" title="Export as Excel"><span _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">Export (Excel)</span></a><!---->
            </li>
            <li _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">
              <!----><a _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" class="lp-theme-link-focus lp-theme-link-hover lp-theme-link-active" tabindex="0" title="Export as CSV"><span _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">Export (CSV)</span></a><!---->
            </li>
            <li _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">
              <!----><a _ngcontent-iyn-c31="" class="lp-theme-link-focus lp-theme-link-hover lp-theme-link-active" tabindex="0" title="Copy Report Link"><span _ngcontent-iyn-c31="">Link</span></a><!---->
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!----></div
```

Full HTML - When Action is Hidden
[image]
You will see that the second square contains information about the dropdown menu and is under the Nav segment

Full HTML - When Action is Visble
[image]

Once you click on actions the DIV contaner is moved out of the Nav segment is now part of the Body Segment

Comment: Anyways you can share the website or html code?

Comment: @NicLaforge Sorry I cannot share the link or code as this is an internal website...can i share just a snip of the 2 elements?

Comment: Yes sure, I am confuse why you need ActionChains tho. Seems that you have to click on an Action menu to display the nav menu. Can you provide a snip when the menu is hidden and when it is displayed.

Comment: @NicLaforge I am using ActionChains because if i do Share.click() the script is not clicking...also as for the code snips i have added it to the question as the HTML elements are fairly large.

Comment: Have you looked at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58997720/selenium-javascriptexception-javascript-error-failed-to-execute-elementfrompo. You mention that the menu will move outside the element. From the code provided you are using ``find_elements``` with ```index=0```. Have you check how many elements were found. I suspect two and you click the wrong one maybe? If that is the case, you can improve the css_selector to select the one under the proper element. Furthermore are you sure when it fails the menu is actually opened?

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Failed to execute 'elementsFromPoint' on 'Document': The provided double value is non-finite.
```

...implies that the [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) instance was unable to find the desired element using the [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) for one or the other reasons:

- The *locator strategy* doesn't identifies the desired element uniquely within the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes).
- The element wasn't **interactable** when you tried to interact with it using the line:

  ```
  action.move_to_element(share).click(share).perform()
  ```
- Element is within an `<iframe>` / `<frame>`
- The style attribute of the element contains **`display: none;`**
- Element is within an [shadow DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59168840/selenium-c-sharp-not-able-to-click-on-an-element-within-shadow-root-closed/59170870#59170870).

---

### Analysis

The relevant HTML would have been helpful to analyze the issue in a better way. However, you need to take care of a couple of things as follows:

- Ensure that the *locator strategy* identifies the desired element uniquely within the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp).
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  ```
  share = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.movie-rating-summary>span")))[0]
  ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(share).click(share).perform()
  ```

> You can find a relevant detailed discussion in [Is it possible to switch to an element in a frame without using driver.switchTo().frame(“frameName”) in Selenium Webdriver Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47467518/is-it-possible-to-switch-to-an-element-in-a-frame-without-using-driver-switchto/47472200#47472200)

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [javascript error: Failed to execute 'elementsFromPoint' on 'Document': The provided double value is non-finite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59853448/javascript-error-failed-to-execute-elementsfrompoint-on-document-the-provi/59854498#59854498)

Comment: I have attached the full HTML code pictures if you can take a look at that. I am not well versed with Selenium and it is my first time using it.

Comment: @ShivPatel Honestly it's next to impossible constructing any locator from a snapshot of the HTML. Text based HTML helps us to test the code even. Particularly in this question I don't see the HTML with `<span>` containing `Actions`