# Selenium: Find child a tag after getting a list of DOM elements

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

First off, I am a Javascript developer tasked with dealing with Selenium, and I feel the pain QE goes through now lol, so my knowledge of Java is basic. I have the following DOM structure and I need to be able to find "Link Name 1" and click it. I will also have to do the same for the other links in different tests.

```
<div class="some-container">
  <div class="blah"></div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div class="common-class-name">
        <a>Link Name 1</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="common-class-name">
        <a>Link Name 2</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="common-class-name">
        <a>Link Name 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="some-other-container">
  <div class="blah"></div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div class="common-class-name">
        <a>Link Name 1</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="common-class-name">
        <a>Link Name 2</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="common-class-name">
        <a>Link Name 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is one of the things I have tried, the findElementsWithWait is basically a utility function that uses findElements with a wait. This does not work.

```
List<WebElement> list = findElementsWithWait(By.className("common-class-name"));

for (WebElement element: list) {
  WebElement el = element.findElement(By.tagName("a"));
  String text = el.getText();
  // other code would check for the proper text and click...
}
```

What is the best way to get the list of a tags to be able to click them based on text value?

Comment: As I can see from HTML sample links have different texts. Why do you want to collect them in list and then click each by individual text?

Comment: I updated the markup. The page actually can have hundreds of these, they are tooltip flyout menus that are part of a list of items. I am able to use the search box to isolate a single item, so your idea will work, but if I could not, which is the case for other instances, I would like to know how to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to search each anchor node by its *link text*:

```
By.linkText("Link Name 1")
```

If there are multiple links with the same text and unique ancestor, then try search by XPATH

```
By.xpath("//div[@class='some-container']//a[.='Link Name 1']")
By.xpath("//div[@class='some-other-container']//a[.='Link Name 1']")
```

Answer (score 0):

To `click()` on the first link with text as **Link Name 1** within `<div class="some-container">` you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='some-container']//a[text()='Link Name 1']"))).click();
  ```

To create a list of the links with text as **Link Name 1** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50610553/selenium-check-for-the-presence-of-element/50621712#50621712) for the `visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `xpath`:

  ```
  List<WebElement> list = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//div[starts-with(@class, 'some') and contains(@class, 'container')]//a[text()='Link Name 1']"))).click();
  ```