# How to click on the YouTube link within the app widget on Google Homepage using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

```
public class WebDriverDemo {
    public static void main(String\[\] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Kartikeye Pandey\\Desktop\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a\[aria-label='Google apps'\]")).click();
        //driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("\[class='gb_d'\]\[data-pid='23'\]")).click();
        //driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("\[class='tX9u1b'\]\[data-pid='36'\]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span\[class='MrEfLc'\]")).click();
    }
}
```

I want that on google webpage clicking on the three dots is working but clicking into it's submenu is not working. Suppose from three dots I want to open **Youtube** but it is not working

Answer (score 1):

The element/icon with the link to *YouTube* is within an [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the desired *frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50621712/7429447) for the desired *elementToBeClickable*.
- You can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using *cssSelector*:

    ```
    driver.get('https://www.google.com/');
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a[aria-label='Google apps']"))).click();
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("iframe[src*='https://ogs.google.com/u/0/widget/app']")));
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//li/a//span[text()='YouTube']"))).click();
    ```
  - Using *xpath*:

    ```
    driver.get('https://www.google.com/');
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@aria-label='Google apps']"))).click();
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[starts-with(@src, 'https://ogs.google.com/widget/app')]")));
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//li/a//span[text()='YouTube']"))).click();
    ```

Comment: If you are using Selenium 4, `WebDriverWait` doesn't take an integer directly for the time to wait, you need to use `Duration` class. For the actual time to wait `Duration.ofSeconds()` and for the polling interval, `Duration.ofMillis()`

Comment: @hfontanez True, agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is when you want to locate the youtube button for clicking, there are another buttons with the same locator. So Selenium can not click the exact element.

You can try with below xpath and renew your locators.

Google Apps

```
(//a[contains(@aria-label, 'Google apps')])
```

Youtube

```
(//a[@href="https://www.youtube.com/"])
```

you need to pause a while for locate youtube button because it dissappers when mouse move anıther direction. So I opened the debugger on the console side just type'in the below command

```
setTimeout(()=>{debugger;},5000);
```

Comment: That's not the reason.

Comment: there is more than one element with locating path (span\[class='MrEfLc'\]) . I had same experience with my tests also and found a unique element and than my tests worked as expected.

Comment: Sorry, your answer is inaccurate. Your solution will not work because the real issue is that the OP was not switching to the iframe containing the "submenu" items.

Comment: okey, thank you for clarifying explanation.