# Selenium: No such element exception is getting on this http://www.salesfoce.com/ even thought that element exists

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to find an element `By.cssSelector("#e1")`. On this website : [SALESFOCE.COM](http://ww1.salesfoce.com/).

I am trying to find an element on this first button(image below), which is a `<div>`. [image: This button]

From java, I tried By.xPath and By.cssSelector but every time I am getting **No such element exception**.
I also used Implicit and explicit wait still getting same exception.

But if I find using inspect element than it highlights the element.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element `Salesforce` is under `iframe` you need to switch to `iframe` first in order to access the element.

Use `WebdriverWait()` and wait for `frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt()` and use following locator to identify.

Use `WebdriverWait()` and wait for `elementToBeClickable()` and use following locator to identify.

```
driver.get("http://ww1.salesfoce.com/")
new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("#rs>iframe")));

new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[text()='Salesforce']"))).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

The element with the text as ***Salesforce*** is within an [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447)

[image: salesforce_iframe]

---

### Solution

To click on the element with text as ***Salesforce*** within the [website](http://ww1.salesfoce.com/) you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the desired *frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50621712/7429447) for the desired *elementToBeClickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using *xpath*:

    ```
    driver.get("http://ww1.salesfoce.com/");
    new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[starts-with(@src, 'https://www.google.com/afs/ads?adtest')]")));
    new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[text()='Salesforce']"))).click();
    ```