# Cant access an element in iframe for automation test

Tags: java, css, selenium-webdriver, automation

i've dealing with this for to days now and i cant solve it, hope you can help me.

I have this automation POC for a job (which obviously i wont get) where i have to automate something on an oracle page.

The thing is that i'm trying to click on the menu but all elements are in an iframe. So changed the iframe in my program but there is no way to find the css locator that will find that object. I tried to run selenium IDE to stole the locators from it but it didn't work either.

Any idea of what may be happening to me? there are fundamental buttons, like the menu one, i will share with you the HTML thanks in advance for reading me.

The iframe is id="afr::PushIframe" and the element i want is <path class="svg-outline" d="M3 7H25M3 14H25M3 21H25"></path>

Thanks again!!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As the desired element is within a [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the desired *frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50621712/7429447) for the desired *elementToBeClickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using *cssSelector*:

    ```
    new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("iframe[id$='PushIframe']")));
    ```
  - Using *xpath*:

    ```
    new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@id, 'PushIframe')]")));
    ```

Comment: thanks!! after all the element wasnt on the iframe, but it was a tricky xpath

Comment: @ValentinaBianchi I think I addressed your query  of switching within the frame but not of any element.