# How to identify an element through classname even though there are multiple elements with the same classnames using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, xpath-1.0

```
<div class="_2S1VP copyable-text selectable-text" data-tab="1" dir="ltr" spellcheck="true" contenteditable="true"></div>

<div class="_2S1VP copyable-text selectable-text" data-tab="3" dir="ltr" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

I'm a beginner and I've had a hard time distinguishing / specifying the first class over the second one

```
typing = bot.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class = "_1Plpp"]')
```

this doesn't seem to work and just using the class name always brings up the unwanted second one with the same class name, I've noticed that it has data-tab="3" and the other one has data-tab="1"
how would i specify the one with data-tab="1" over the other one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the *class* attribute of both the elements contains similar values, you won't be able to distinguish them only through *class* attribute and you may have to consider the some other attribute(s).

To identify the first element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector` along with *data-tab* attribute:

  ```
  typing = bot.find_element_by_css_selector("div.copyable-text.selectable-text[data-tab='1']")
  ```
- Using `xpath` along with *data-tab* attribute:

  ```
  typing = bot.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'copyable-text') and @data-tab='1']")
  ```
- Using `xpath` along with *data-tab* attribute:

  ```
  typing = bot.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'selectable-text') and @data-tab='1']")
  ```

Comment: That hint about putting dots between element's class names was priceless.