# How to search for multiple attributes selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

HTML:

```
<button type = "submit" class = "car">
```

How should I search for this button in selenium python using both the attributes type and class in `find_element_by_xpath()`

Answer (score 1):

To locate the element using both the attributes **`class`** and **`type`** you can club up them in a single locator and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.car[type='submit']")
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='car' and @type='submit']")
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to identify an element through classname even though there are multiple elements with the same classnames using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62151967/how-to-identify-an-element-through-classname-even-though-there-are-multiple-elem/62152196#62152196)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this XPATH

```
'//button[@type="submit" and @class="car"]'
```