# What are properties of find_element_by_class_name in selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(url)
divs = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('class')
```

Are there any properties of browser.find_element_by_class_name('class')?

For example if I have code like that:

```
<div class="foo">
    <a href="" class="poo">one</a>
    <a href="" class="poo">two</a>
    <a href="" class="poo">three</a>
</div>
<div class="foo">
    <a href="" class="koo">one</a>
    <a href="" class="koo">two</a>
    <a href="" class="koo">three</a>
</div>
```

I want to get text from 'a' tags.
But firstly I want to get divs.
so I do something like that:

```
divs = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('foo')
```

And now I want to get all the 'a' tags from my divs Array. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find elements in a element, extract them with nested loop:

```
divs = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('foo')

for div in divs:
    elements = div.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
    for element in elements:
        print(element.text)
```

Comment: @frianH OP wanted to _want to get `<divs>`_ but your answer gives _class_ `foo` got lucky ehh?

Comment: Hi @DebanjanB I don't think we need to debate `divs`, it is just a variable name.

Comment: _"And now I want to get all the 'a' tags from my divs Array. Is it possible?"_

Comment: yes @DebanjanB, I think the above answer has answered the main question, get all `a` tag from each `div` in `divs`. CMIIW

Answer (score 2):

### `CLASS_NAME`

[`CLASS_NAME`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.by.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.by) is one of the [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) supported [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) as well as a property of the [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) interface which gets and sets the value of the `class` attribute of the specified element.

To get the *texts* from `<a>` tags with in parent `<div>` tags you can use either of the following *Locator Strategies*:

- Using `CLASS_NAME`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "koo")))])
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.foo a.koo")))])
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='foo']//a[@class='koo']")))])
  ```

Comment: Yes, I know. But can I somehow get the text of the anchor tags that are within my divs?
I mean I wanted to do something like:
divs.find_elements_by_tag_name('a'). But I can't do something like that, since I'm getting a huge error.

Comment: And what does that error say? Is it "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_tag_name'?

Comment: Never mind, everything is working. Thank you very much.