# How do i click this element via className since i will be using it for multiple screens with same class name

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, classname

The element I got is `<div class="x-tool x-box-item" id="tool-123" src="data:image/gif;base64" class="new-img x-tool-maximize".`

I particularly need this `class="new-img x-tool-maximize"` because its the common of all the screen.

I already tried

```
driver.findElement(By.className("new-img.x-tool-maximize")).click()
```

and

```
driver.findElement(By.className("new-img x-tool-maximize")).click();
```

and

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'value') and contains(@class, 'test')]"))``;
```

Comment: Why does the div contain two class attributes? `class="x-tool x-box-item"` and `class="new-img x-tool-maximize"`? AFAIK `By.className` only accepts a single classname

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a CSS selector to find this type of element. You’ll want something like `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.new-img.x-tool-maximize"))`.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use list in selenium if you have multiple elements with same locators 

  

     List<WebElement> classes=driver.findElements(By.classname("new-img x-tool-maximize));
// if you want click 1 st class name element use this following line 
     classes.get(0).click();

OR  // if you want click 2 nd  class name element use this following line 
     classes.get(1).click();
```

Comment: This won’t work. The `By.className` will throw an exception because the argument contains multiple class names, since class names are delimited by white space in HTML.

Comment: can you share url of this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a list to get all the WebElements with specific classes

```
 List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.new-img.x-tool-maximize"));
```

Answer (score 0):

As you intent to `click()` on the element using only the `className` attribute values, ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *cssSelector* using only the `className` attribute values:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector(".new-img.x-tool-maximize"))).click();
  ```

For a more canonicl approach you can indlude the *tagName* as follows:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div.new-img.x-tool-maximize]"))).click();
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Unable to locate element using className in Selenium and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62948150/unable-to-locate-element-using-classname-in-selenium-and-java/62949723#62949723)
- [How to locate the last web element using classname attribute through Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62957266/how-to-locate-the-last-web-element-using-classname-attribute-through-selenium-an/62959237#62959237)
- [What are properties of find_element_by_class_name in selenium python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62716634/what-are-properties-of-find-element-by-class-name-in-selenium-python/62716829#62716829)