# Unable to locate element using className in Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I wanted to locate a element of a web page using class name in Selenium. This is the web element that I tried:

```
<button class="signup-button b green">Get Started!</button>
```

When I try this way, I was unable to locate the button;

```
driver.findElement(By.className("signup-button")).click();
```

But, using css selector like below, it was working;

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.signup-button")).click();
```

What is the reason for that sometimes working and other times not working?

Comment: Please check that your page doesn't have iFrame elements first. If it has, you should switch to the needed frame before 'findEelement'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are able to locate the following element:

```
<button class="signup-button b green">Get Started!</button>
```

using:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.signup-button")).click();
```

but was unable to locate the same element using:

```
driver.findElement(By.className("signup-button")).click();
```

That's because there were other elements which renders within the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) with *className* as **`signup-button`** even before the desired element, which possibly may be **invisible** by design.

Ideally, you should also be able to use a [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='signup-button' and text()='Get Started!']")).click();
```

---

### Best Practices

But as per best practices, you need to use [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button.signup-button"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class='signup-button' and text()='Get Started!']"))).click();
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [NoSuchElementException, Selenium unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48471321/nosuchelementexception-selenium-unable-to-locate-element/48472940#48472940)

Comment: Thank You for Your Answer. I satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use relative xpath , if you could not have locators like id and class name
Can you try with **//button[contains(text(),"Get Started!")]** this xpath