# How to locate the last web element using classname attribute through Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, getattribute

```
getphone = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_3ko75')[-1]
phone = getphone.get_attribute("title")
```

Not working I need to get the title on string format.

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
'WebElement' object is not subscriptable
  File "C:\Users\vmaiha\Documents\Python Projects\Project 01\WP_Answer.py", line 43, in check
    getphone = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_3ko75')[-1]
```

Comment: @andrea still not working:

        getphone = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_3ko75')[-1]
        phone = getphone.get_attribute("title")

Comment: I only edited your question in order to organize in a better way the code. I did not provide any answer

Comment: Thank you Andrea

Comment: find_element return only a single WebElement Object. Why do you use [-1] at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code trials, to get the title of the last [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) based on the value of the *classname* attribute you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`, `find_element*` and `last()`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='_3ko75'][last()]").get_attribute("title"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`, `find_elements*` and `[-1]`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='_3ko75']")[-1].get_attribute("title"))
  ```

Preferably using [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336):

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@class='_3ko75'][last()]"))).get_attribute("title"))
```

or

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@class='_3ko75']")))[-1].get_attribute("title"))
```