# How can I find list elements by tag name and class in Selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

My website has many span tags:

```html
<span class="aaa bbb ccc ddd">
    <span class="eee"></span>
    <span class="ggg"></span>
    <a href="#" class="hhh">Text</a>
</span>
```

I need to find all span tags with class = "ddd" and click all. With Selenium, I just found *find_elements_by_tag_name* and *find_element_by_class_name*, but I don't know how to find element with both conditions. I tried:

```
listEle = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("span")
for a in listEle:
    print(a.get_attribute('class'))
    if "ddd" in a.get_attribute('class'):
        a.click()
```

But I get the error message:

> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

Comment: This error

    selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
implies that the desired element was not interactable when you tried to invoke **click()** on it.

Comment: So I have to find the <Span> tag and click on the <a> tag in the <span> tag?

Comment: Hi what seems to be the problem?

Comment: Xpath solved the problem:
`listSpan = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'dynatree-folder')]/a")
        for a in listSpan:
        #    a.find_element_by_class_name("statusDie")
            a.click()
            time.sleep(5)`

Comment: From [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30002313/selenium-finding-elements-by-class-name-in-python#comment128785684_30025430): *"`find_element_by_*` and `find_elements_by_*` are removed in Selenium 4.3.0. Use `find_element` instead."*. Though it doesn't really answer the question what can be done if the number of elements is different from exactly one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem:

- To find elements with tag name and class name, I use an XPath expression:

  ```python
  elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'ddd')]/a")
  ```
- The tag I can click is the <a> tag, not the <span> tag as I did before.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='ddd']//a")

for elem in elems:
   elem.click()
```

Comment: I tried but didn't see any element, maybe because span tag has multiple class groups (aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd), i think need to use contain

Comment: Ok, then try this, 

elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'ddd')]//a")

for elem in elems:
   elem.click()