# Python Selenium Unable to acquire element

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to write a program that automates the whole process of joining a webex meeting. However after having read the documentation on how to get an element through id, Xpath etc nothing seems to work.

```py
from selenium import webdriver

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("link")

element = driver.find_element_by_ #?#

element.send_keys("some text")
```

HTML:

[image: Site]

I guess my question is: how do I acquire the appropriate element in order to add my name?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium Finding elements by class name in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30002313/selenium-finding-elements-by-class-name-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Use the class name

```
browser.find_element_by_class_name("style-input-2nuAK undefined")
```

Comment: element.send_keys("sometext")
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'send_keys                                                              
  I seem to be getting this bug any ideas?   here is the code                                            
 from selenium import webdriver


PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("link")

element = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("style-input-2nuAK undefined")
element.send_keys("sometext")

Comment: You're using `find_elements_by_class_name`, which returns a list of web elements, so you cannot use the `send_keys` method there. Change that to `find_element_by_class_name`  (singular).

Comment: @MikeCode 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Γιώργος\Desktop\Wx.py", line 9, in <module>
    element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('style-input-2nuAK undefined')
  File "C:\Users\Γιώργος\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 564, in find_element_by_class_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)
  File "C:\Users\Γιώργος\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']'

Comment: File "C:\Users\Γιώργος\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Γιώργος\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

Comment: It's not able to find web-element with `.style-input-2nuAK undefined` class.  There could be two issues for this. 1) Your locator is incorrect. 2) Your code is trying to access element before it being loaded into DOM. Try introducing `time.sleep()` before you that grab element.

Comment: @George if the issue is due to the delay in element rendering. Introduce implicit wait `driver.implicitly_wait(5)` and that should solve the issue for all elements.

Comment: @MikeCode from selenium import webdriver


PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get("link")
driver.find_element_by_class_name("style-input-2nuAK undefined")
element.send_keys("sometext")
    
I suppose you mean this, however im still getting the same error any other ideas?

Comment: @George I have posted my solution code. Try with that.

Answer (score 0):

To send a *character sequence* to the element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.undefined[placeholder='Your full name']").send_keys("George")
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@class, 'undefined') and @placeholder='Your full name']").send_keys("George")
  ```

---

Ideally, to send a *character sequence* to the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.undefined[placeholder='Your full name']"))).send_keys("George")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[contains(@class, 'undefined') and @placeholder='Your full name']"))).send_keys("George")
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Do i need to intall anything else ?

Comment: I don't think you need to install anything unless you are using Nuget packages. With Nuget packages you may need `SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers` package.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Γιώργος\Desktop\Wx.py", line 12, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//inut[contains(@class, 'undefined') and @placeholder='Your full name']"))).send_keys("George")
  File "C:\Users\Γιώργος\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
Im getting this bug any ideas on what im doing wrong ?

Comment: from selenium import webdriver


PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get('link')

element = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('style-input-2nuAK undefined')
element.send_keys('sometext')
Also tried this but then i get this error : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Γιώργος\Desktop\Wx.py", line 10, in <module>
    element.send_keys('sometext')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'send_keys'

Answer (score 0):

**CSS** for the element

input[placeholder="Your email address"]

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[placeholder="Your email address"]").send_keys("George")
```

**XPath** for the element

//input[@placeholder="Your email address"]

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder="Your email address"]").send_keys("George")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code.I have tested this using publicly available login page

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.get("https://signin.webex.com/signin")
email_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='el-input']/input")
email_input.clear()
email_input.send_keys('test@test.com')
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='el-button next el-button--primary']").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'meetingsamer37.webex.com')]").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("continue-button").click()
password_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@aria-label='Password']")
password_input.send_keys('test')
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='el-button next el-button--primary']").click()
```

Comment: Apparently i needed to add driver.switch_to.frame("pbui_iframe") and  then locating the element by xpath. Thank you for taking the time to explain