# Get multiple elements by tag with Python and Selenium

Tags: python, css, selenium, css-selectors

My code goes into a website and scrapes rows of information (title and time).

However, there is one tag ('p') that I am not sure how to get using 'get element by'.

On the website, it is the information under each title.

Here is my code so far:

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.nutritioncare.org/ASPEN21Schedule/#tab03_19')
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
eachRow = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('timeline__item')
time.sleep(1)
for item in eachRow:
    time.sleep(1)
    title = item.find_element_by_class_name('timeline__item-title')
    tim = item.find_element_by_class_name('timeline__item-time')
    tex = item.find_element_by_tag_name('p') # This is the part I don’t know how to scrape
    print(title.text, tim.text, tex.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the page and there are several p tags, I suggest to use [find_elements_by_tag_name](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements_by_tag_name) instead of `find_element_by_tag_name` (to get all the p tags including the p tag that you want) and iterate over all the p tags elements and then join the text content and do [strip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.strip) on it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import requests
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://www.nutritioncare.org/ASPEN21Schedule/#tab03_19')
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
eachRow = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('timeline__item')
time.sleep(1)
for item in eachRow:
    time.sleep(1)
    title=item.find_element_by_class_name('timeline__item-title')
    tim=item.find_element_by_class_name('timeline__item-time')
    tex=item.find_elements_by_tag_name('p')
    text = " ".join([i.text for i in tex]).strip()
    print(title.text,tim.text, text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the webpage has several `p` tags, it would be better to use the `.find_elements_by_class()` method. Replace the `print` call in the code with the following:

```
    print(title.text,tim.text)
    for t in tex:
        if t.text == '':
            continue
        print(t.text)
```

Comment: From [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30002313/selenium-finding-elements-by-class-name-in-python#comment128785684_30025430): *"`find_element_by_*` and `find_elements_by_*` are removed in Selenium 4.3.0. Use `find_element` instead."*. Though it doesn't really answer the question what can be done if the number of elements is different from exactly one. There may be a canonical Stack Overflow answer somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using different *find_elements_by_class*... I don't use Python that much, but try this unless you already have.

Comment: The p tag does not have a class name unfortunately

Comment: what does 'p' represent?

Comment: paragraph, not sure if its considered tag or css selector etc

Comment: id know then because tag name shouldwork but if it doesn't i guess i can't help sorry

Comment: unless xpath. (//p[text() = 'JBL']) works