# Selenium can't find leaflet-interactive elements

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, leaflet

I'm trying to get elements on a webpage that has a `react-leaflet` map. The import on the page is the following:

```js
// Map.js component

import { Map, TileLayer, GeoJSON, Pane } from 'react-leaflet'

...
  return(
    <Map
      <TileLayer ... />
    />
  )
```

Then the DOM looks like this:

```html
<div class="leaflet-container">
  <div class="leaflet-pane">
    <div class="leaflet-pane custom-pane">
      <svg class="leaflet-zoom-animated">
        <g>
          <path class="leaflet-interactive">...</path>
          <path class="leaflet-interactive">...</path>
          <path class="leaflet-interactive">...</path>
          <path class="leaflet-interactive">...</path>
          <path class="leaflet-interactive">...</path>
        </g>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I query the elements in the browser console I get all the `<path>` elements

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.leaflet-interactive')
// NodeList(5)
```

But when I try to get from my Python script it can't find the elements:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_options("detach", True)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

wait.until(EC.url_contains("map"))

driver.get(url) # the webpage url
wait.until(EC.url_contains(f"{latitude}/{longitude}"))

# the following step fails
elements = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "leaflet-interactive")))
```

Unfortunately, it does not give me any useful errors (no exceptions actually).

I was looking at other questions but looks like my code is right - https://stackoverflow.com/a/63329510/11228445

Is this an issue on leaflet renders the page? I can't see any layers or iframes being rendered.

Answer (score 1):

After some experimentation, I verified that switching to

```py
# any instead of all
elements = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_any_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "leaflet-interactive")))
```

returned the right amount of elements.

So what it most likely be happening is that not all elements are being rendered in the current viewport (the window is 800 x 600); therefore, switching to `any` instead of `all` should suffice in this case.

Comment: What was the wait time?

Comment: I had it set for 30 seconds