# If element is not shown with isDisplayed(), I'm getting error

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**My scenario**

1. access a specific page
2. While showing the element, should I click it
3. If don't show this element, ignore

**My code**

```
exports.checkButton = function (driver) {

    driver.findElement(By.css(".btn.btn-danger.pull-right.remove-promotion")).then(function(button){ 

        if (button.isDisplayed()) {

            console.log("Displaying"); 

    } else { 

            console.log("not displayed");

    }
});
```

**My problem**

If the element is not displayed, it does not show the message `console.log("not displayed");` and I'm getting error:

```
Uncaught NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".btn.btn-danger.pull-right.remove-promotion"}
```

Comment: Check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148857/check-if-element-exists-selenium-javascript-node-js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isDisplayed()` can be used only when the element exists in the DOM, but be hidden (for example, contains `style="display: none"`).
I think, in your case, the element doesn't exist in the DOM when it is not displayed, that's why you get the exception NoSuchElementError.

Please try:

```
export.checkButton = function (driver) {    
        driver.findElement(By.css(".btn.btn-danger.pull-right.remove-promotion")).then(function(button){ 
            console.log("Displaying");
            button.click();
            return true;
        }).catch(function (ex) {
            console.log("not displayed");
            return false;
        });
}

var display = checkButton(driver);
while (display) {
    display = checkButton(driver);
}
```

Note: You should check the DOM first to see how it behaves in both cases - when the element exists and not exists.

Comment: in fact I need use this catch with while. For example, while the button is present, run `console.log("Displaying")`. Do you have any example for this? Because I'm trying here but no success

Comment: So you use my code above with no success? What did it show? Any error? Did you check whether your css is correct?

Comment: @LihnNguyen Your code works perfectly, but I need to use with `while`and `catch`to perform many times the block code while `button` is displayed. Example?

Comment: I updated the code with a `click()` if the element exists.
I don't understand why you need a `while`? Maybe you can update your scenario?

Comment: because is a page with several entries, so while these records are being displayed, I need to remove them and, when it does not exist any more, I running catch :)

Comment: Are they displayed at the same time, or when you remove 1, another might appear?

Comment: Second option :) When I remove one, another can appears

Comment: Please update your question with your new scenario then. I will update my answer according to it

Comment: Please check if the code is close to what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure an element is displayed, you first need to be sure it actually exists in the DOM. In Java you can check it like this:

```
public boolean isElementPresentInDom(By by) {
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    boolean isElementPresent = (driver.findElements(by).size() != 0);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(driverTimeOut, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); // I have a driverTimeOut variable, I set the default timeout to zero in the beginning of this method to make it fast, then I set it to my driverTimeOut again. I recommend you to do the same :)
    return isElementPresent;
}
```

(Don't know how to translate it exactly in Javascript, but you've got the main idea.)
If this method returns `true`, then you can check if your element is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Using `.isDisplayed()` assumes that the element exists. You are getting that error because the element doesn't exist. Either your locator is off or the element maybe hasn't loaded yet, etc. Use `.findElements()` (plural) and make sure the size is > 0 to see if the element exists. Ideally you would wrap that in a function and use it when needed. Once you determine the element exists, *then* check `.isDisplayed()` and the code should work.